# Dynamic Dropdown showing duplicate value Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, dynamic, controller, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Trying to set the Logged in user as a drop down selected value but when i check the list of drop down value it shows me repeated values like Admin.I am generating drop down values from users table stored in database....Please Help to resolve this issue.

**Here is the DropDown of Users and Admin is selected as current user.**

[image]

**Users Controller:**

```
 $users = User::all();
 $current_user = Auth::user()->name;
```

**Dynamic Drop Down in Laravel Blade..**

```
<select name="recieved_by" class="form-control">
  <option value="{{ $current_user }}" selected>{{ $current_user }}</option>
  @foreach($users as $user)
     <option value="{{$user->name}}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use **groupBy** in your query to remove duplicates.

Also remove current user from the query so that it will not repeat in your select drop down like below:

```
$current_user = Auth::user()->name; 
$users = User::where('name','!=',$current_user)->groupBy('name')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $users = array(); //declare an array

    @foreach($users as $user)
        $users['name'] = $user->name;
    @endforeach
    $users = array_unique($users);
```

before you use your `foreach()` loop

Hope this will help you.

Please check the syntax as am not a laravel developer

Thanks,

Comment: it gives me this error 
array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: $users is your array or object ?

Comment: $users is an array of objects...each object contains the data of user

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="recieved_by" class="form-control">

       @foreach($users as $user)
           @if($current_user==$user->name)
              <option value="{{ $current_user }}" selected>{{ $current_user }}</option>
           @endif
           <option value="{{$user->name}}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
       @endforeach

</select>
```